# Deleting a specific div tag with button using .onclick event listener

Tags: jquery, dynamic, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I'm new to coding overall. I have new div tags being generated with an onclick event, and that works fine. I have created and appended a new button on each div tag in case a user wants to delete that div tag. But my problem is that I can't seem to be able to create an onclick event to delete that specific div by clicking on the button.

I don't want to delete all my div tags, just the one div tag specific to where the button is located.

```
// variable for using the search functionality and adding it to the itinerary for the first day
var itineraryInput = $("#search").val();

console.log(itineraryInput);

var row = $("<div>");
    row.addClass("attraction");
    row.append("<p>" + itineraryInput + "</p>");
    // row.append("<button>" + "<button>" + "<button>");

var newButton1 = $("<button>" + "<p> Add to  leave a review </p>");
    newButton1.addClass("newButton");

    row.append(newButton1);

var newButton2 = $("<button>");
    newButton2.addClass("newButton");

    row.append(newButton2);

var newButton3 = $("<button>");
    newButton3.addClass("newButton");
    newButton3.attr("id", "deleteButton");

    row.append(newButton3);

    $("#first").prepend(row);
    // $("#first").append(attButton);
})

$("#deleteButton").on("click", function() {
    $(".div").remove();
});
```

Nothing is deleting.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xqrhwk8a/1/ In case anyone wants to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to add an event (your `click`) to a button that still there isn't in your document because it is dynamic.

So your solution could be find here => [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Technically **this is a duplicate question**, but since you are writing a code that is too complicated for what it has to do, I try to point you to a much simpler way.

You are adding a lot of `append` & `addClass` that create recursive and dirty code.
A solution to make it more drier could be to use a single variable with all your buttons and prepend only that.

```
var row="";

row+="<div class='attraction'>";
row+="<p>" + itineraryInput + "</p>";
row+="<button class='newButton review'>Add to leave a review</button>";
row+="<button class='newButton doSomething'>Do something</button>";
row+="<button class='newButton deleteButton'>Remove itinerary</button>";
row+="</div>";

$("#first").prepend(row);
```

After that you can use the solution that I post you before to add your event to delete button:

```
$(document).on("click", ".deleteButton", function() {
    $(this).closest(".attraction").remove();
});
```

To add another events to the others buttons the technique is the same.

This is your code in action with a working delete buttons:

```js
$("#search-submit").on("click", function() {

  var itineraryInput = $("#search").val();

  var row="";
  row+="<div class='attraction'>";
  row+="<p>" + itineraryInput + "</p>";
  row+="<button class='newButton review'>Add to  leave a review</button>";
  row+="<button class='newButton something'>Do something</button>";
  row+="<button class='newButton deleteButton'>Remove itinerary</button>";
  row+="</div>";

  $("#first").prepend(row);
})

$(document).on("click", ".deleteButton", function() {
    $(this).closest(".attraction").remove();
});
```

```css
.newButton {
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map" style="height: 100%"></div>
<div class="row mb-2">
   <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search for an attraction...">
      <button id="search-submit" class="btn btn-lg pull-right">Add To Your Itinerary!</button>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="trans_container">
   <div id="trans_first"></div>
   <div id="trans_second"></div>
</div>
<div class="acontainer">
   <div id="first"></div>
   <div id="second"></div>
   <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**Edit 1**
I reply to your comment.

You can use `appendTo` to... append a content wherever you want with jQuery. I post you an example. In this, I take my itinerary and put it in div `#second` clicking the button named "*Append to #second*".
(In your comment you forgot a dot (`.`) before `something` ('cause `something` is a class, maybe this was the problem):

```
$(document).on("click", ".something", function() { 
                     /* ^^^ write a dot here */  
    $("div").appendTo("#second"); 
});
```

```js
$("#search-submit").on("click", function() {

  var itineraryInput = $("#search").val();

  var row="";
  row+="<div class='attraction'>";
  row+="<p>" + itineraryInput + "</p>";
  row+="<button class='newButton review'>Add to  leave a review</button>";
  row+="<button class='newButton something'>Append to #second</button>";
  row+="<button class='newButton deleteButton'>Remove itinerary</button>";
  row+="<div class='green'></div>";
  row+="</div>";

  $("#first").prepend(row);
})

$(document).on("click", ".deleteButton", function() {
    $(this).closest(".attraction").remove();
});


$(document).on("click", ".something", function() { 
  var parent=$(this).closest(".attraction");

  $("p", parent).appendTo("#second"); 
});
```

```css
.newButton {
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row mb-2">
   <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search for an attraction...">
      <button id="search-submit" class="btn btn-lg pull-right">Add To Your Itinerary!</button>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="trans_container">
   <div id="trans_first"></div>
   <div id="trans_second"></div>
</div>
<div class="acontainer">
   <div id="first"></div>
   <div id="second"></div>
   <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would I be able to do something like this: ```$(document).on("click", "something", function() { $("div").appendTo("#second"); }); ```to move a specific div to another container? 

I only ask since the jQuery documentation mentions that we can also select an element on the page and insert it into another y utilizing ```appendTo```. But I can't figure it out.